# Question about associated primes in Eisenbud's commutative algebra.

Tags: commutative-algebra

This statement comes from Eisenbud's book on commutative algebra.

Suppose we have a module $M = M' \bigoplus M'' $ and suppose that $P \in Ass M - Ass M'$. He claims that if $x\in M$ has annihilator P, so $\textbf{Rx $\cong$ R/P}$, then since $P$ is prime every nonzero submodule of $Rx$ also has annihilator $P$.

Could someone explain me why the black part is true and how we get the conclusion of the claim? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

$\mathfrak p$ is the kernel of the linear map $\;\begin{aligned}[t]R&\longrightarrow M,\\\lambda&\longmapsto \lambda x.\end{aligned}$

What is the image of this map?

*Added*: A non-zero submodule of $Rx$ corresponds to a non-zero ideal in $R/\mathfrak p$, which is an integral domain.

Comment: It's not clear how this shows that "*every nonzero submodule of $Rx$ also has annihilator $P$*", but to be honest I'll let this part to the OP who showed not much effort on trying to understand his own question.